# Create a Monthly Label value by last day of month

Tags: sql, hive, window-functions, row-number

I have a dataset that I have applied a

```
row_num() partition by month order by day_date desc
```

My results are such, not limited to - just for example

```
Month        Day            User        Active        row_num
Jan-2021     2021-01-28     A           yes            1
Jan-2021     2021-01-27     A           yes            2
Jan-2021     2021-01-28     A           yes            3
Feb-2021     2021-02-25     A           no             1
Feb-2021     2021-02-15     A           yes            2
Feb-2021     2021-02-01     A           no             3
Jan-2021     2021-01-28     B           yes            1
Jan-2021     2021-01-28     B           yes            2
Jan-2021     2021-01-28     B           yes            3
Feb-2021     2021-02-28     B           no             1
Feb-2021     2021-02-08     B           yes            2
```

The appendage I would like to add is, if the user is active at the end of their month, I would like to label the month active.  Logic is if row_num = 1 and active = yes, label full month, yes vice versa row_num = 1 and active = no label month_active = no.

I am currently stuck at how to apply a value to the partition of the month but evaluate at the daily level.  Appreciate it in advance.

```
Month        Day            User        Active        row_num        month_active
Jan-2021     2021-01-28     A           yes            1             yes
Jan-2021     2021-01-27     A           yes            2             yes
Jan-2021     2021-01-28     A           yes            3             yes
Feb-2021     2021-02-25     A           no             1             no
Feb-2021     2021-02-15     A           yes            2             no
Feb-2021     2021-02-01     A           no             3             no             
Jan-2021     2021-01-28     B           yes            1             yes
Jan-2021     2021-01-28     B           yes            2             yes
Jan-2021     2021-01-28     B           yes            3             yes
Feb-2021     2021-02-28     B           no             1             no
Feb-2021     2021-02-08     B           yes            2             no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `first_value()`:

```
select t.*,
       first_value(active) over (partition by month order by day desc) as month_active
from t;
```

Or if you use your query as a subquery, you can use:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then active end) over (partition by month) as month_active
from t;
```

Comment: I aspire to be as well as you!